# can I set more than one .whereEqualTo pointing to a field in a document in a firestore query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document that has `city` as a field. I want to query a document which has

`city == "Tokyo`" and `city == "Osaka"`.

how to do that ?

I have tried this one:

```
query = ref
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CITY,"Tokyo")
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CITY,"Osaka")
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_IS_ACTIVE,true)
            .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_HAS_BEEN_APPROVED,false)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,now.toDate())

          .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,oneMonthFromNow.toDate())
            .orderBy(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .limit(limit)
```

but I don't receive any document, If I only set one query pointing to 
a city, like this only `.whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CITY,"Tokyo")` , then it works, but it only give me all documents that has tokyo in the city field

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field, and you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

```
citiesRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("state", "CA")
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("state", "IN");
citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
        .whereGreaterThan("population", 1000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing when you say you want `city == "Tokyo" and city == "Osaka"` you meant `OR`. Firestore recently released `OR` logic

```
query = ref
        .whereIn(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_CITY,Arrays.asList("Tokyo", "Osaka"))
        .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_IS_ACTIVE,true)
        .whereEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_HAS_BEEN_APPROVED,false)
 .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,now.toDate())
 .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME,oneMonthFromNow.toDate())
        .orderBy(FIRESTORE_EVENT_FIELD_DATE_START_TIME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .limit(limit)
```

In your current query, you are not receiving any document because your first two `where` are mutually exclusive

Comment: I just read the documentation about the OR logic, is the field should be in Array ? in my case, the field data type of my city is string

Comment: It has to be array of your data type. In your case array of string

Comment: You may have a look at this article: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d. It gives a solution for the JS SDK but the concept is the same for the Android SDK. Disclaimer: I’m the author.